# Control data locality in Impala by partitioning

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, partitioning, database-partitioning, impala

I would like to avoid Impala nodes unnecessarily requesting data from other nodes over the network in cases when the **ideal data locality or layout is known** at table creation time. This would be helpful with 'non-additive' operations where all records from a partition are needed at the same place (node) anyway (for ex. percentiles).

**Is it possible to tell Impala that all data in a partition should always be co-located on a single node for any HDFS replica?**

In Impala-SQL, I am not sure if the "PARTITIONED BY" clause provide this feature. In my understanding, Impala chunks its partitions into separate files on HDFS but HDFS does not guarantee the co-location of related files nor blocks by default (rather tries to achieve the opposite).

Found some information about Impala's impact on HDFS development but not clear if these are already implemented or still in plans:

http://www.slideshare.net/deview/aaron-myers-hdfs-impala
(slides 23-24)

Thank you in advance for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the slides you mention ("Co-located block replicas") - it's about an HDFS feature ([HDFS-2576](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2576)) implemented in Hadoop 2.1. It provides a Java API to give hints to HDFS as to where the blocks should be placed.

It's not used in Impala as of 2014, but it definitely seems like building some groundwork for that - as it would give Impala a performance equivalent of specifying distribution key in traditional MPP databases.

Answer (score -1):

No, that completely defeats the purpose of having a distributed file system and MPP computing.  It also creates a single point of failure and a bottleneck especially if you're talking about a 250GB table that is joined to itself.  Exactly the kind of problems that Hadoop was designed to solve.  Partitioning data creates sub-directories in HDFS on the namenode and that data is then replicated throughout the datanodes in the cluster.

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. There are Impala partitions (HDFS files), HDFS chunks of these files and HDFS replicas of these chunks. The aim is to keep all chunks related to a partition and a **single replica** together on the same node. Replicas would still be placed on different nodes but all data of any partition would be local to the node which is important to avoid copying over the network for some operations.

Please have a look at the **slides** mentioned above from Aaron Myers (Software Engineer at Cloudera and an Apache Hadoop Committer) for more details.