# How to place HDFS file blocks with same / shared partitioning applied for different files / tables on same Data Node

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop2

I have two big tables partitioned by date column. They are saved as parquet files in hdfs. Every partition is divided by blocks of 64 MB and replicated 3 times accross the cluster machines. To optimize join operation I want to place the same date partitions on the same machines (any join key value is placed in one date partition only).

In Spark there is Partitioner object which can help to distribute blocks of different RDDs accross the cluster. Its pretty similar to my question but I'm afraid that after saving these RDD's file blocks may be shuffled by hdfs mechanism. 
Explaned: RDD is Spark instance and df method saveAsTable(...) calls (I suppose) some low-level functions which choose data nodes and replicate the data.

Can anyone help me to know if the blocks of my tables are distributed the right way?

Comment: Hi @eakotelnikov , welcome to SO! Can you repartition the two parquet files by the date column before you save them to HDFS? If that is outside your control, I think you have no choice but to repartition after reading the files (which means you cannot avoid the shuffle). Also, I am not clear what you mean by 'after saving these RDD's file blocks may be shuffled by hdfs mechanism'? Could you edit your question to elaborate that part?

Comment: I think you mean you want to tell Hadoop / HDFS to put "same" partitions on same data nodes / workers. I am not convinced that can be done.

Comment: Thank you for attention! Tables I mentioned in question are already exist on hdfs but new partition appends every day. I can control the process of writing but I didn't found any information how to put same partitions on same data nodes.

Comment: I will be glad to now if it is possible, but I am sure it is not for files. bucketBy may help you.

Comment: @thebluephantom, thanks for idea of bucketing, it will accelerate join, but same partition blocks (even bucketed) will locate on different data nodes. Is the choise of blocks location completely random (except "rack" rules)?

Comment: @suj1th, I explained a bit. I could try an experiment: read two tables, repartition them using the same Partition object, save and compare join time. Is it right way of test the idea?

Comment: I think so, but that is more about replicas. bucketBy is for now only for SPARK, ETL imo, cannot be read from Hive, Impala.

Comment: When JOINing though, my understanding is that the shuffling ensures that the partitions  for JOINing go to same worker. In non-S3 the workers are the data nodes as far as I know. But JOINing is different to persisting files.

Comment: Distributing the right way would mean OK for this, but not for some other requirement

Comment: Was the r value in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that one cannot control placement of "like / similar" data blocks in terms of partitioning for logically related files / tables expressly. I.e. you cannot influence on which data nodes data blocks are placed by HDFS.

These partitions / chunks of data may coincidentally reside on same data nodes / workers (due to replication by HDFS.

As an aside, with S3 such an approach does not work in any event as the concept of data locality optimization does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for explain. Can you please take a look at [Control data locality in Impala by partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797968/control-data-locality-in-impala-by-partitioning)? Feature mentioned there seems to be helpful to 'influence on which data nodes data blocks are placed by HDFS'.

Comment: Interesting. Does not change my point of view though. It's quite vague and tals of HBase. Also it talks about creation time. In any event, what if the Data Node is near full? I, as Big Data Architect, have never gone this level, never heard of this either from my colleagues. Sounds like ORACLE clustering. Not saying it would be a bad idea though, but Hadoop relies on MPP brute force to a high degree.